# SharePoint List LookUp field to use API to populate choices

Tags: api, spfieldlookupvalue

When creating a list in SharePoint, you can choose the "LookUp" field.  I would like to have that "LookUp" be able grab information from an API from a different site.  Any way to get this process started.  Any feedback is good feedback.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really do that.  Lookup columns are meant to refer to other lists in SharePoint.

As suggested in [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/114586/8992), an approach you might be able to take is to create an [External Content Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/external-content-types-in-sharepoint) to pull data from your external API into SharePoint, then set up an [External Data column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-update-an-external-data-column-in-a-list-or-library-44eff2c5-8051-489d-989c-f5d09f527aee) on your list that refers to the External Content Type.

Comment: Would I need to use SharePoint Designer 2013 in order to accomplish the External Data column?

Comment: I don't think for the column part, no, but I believe you _would_ need it for setting up the External Content Type.  It's a two step process - set up the External Content Type (for this I believe you do need SharePoint Designer), once that is done, create an External Data Column that points to the External Content Type (for that I believe you do _not_ need SharePoint Designer).